# How to get total No. of players from Leaderboard

Tags: ios, leaderboard, marmalade

Is there any way I can get how many player has played my game and successfully reported the score on Leaderboard?

I am currently working on Marmalade for iOS, so I'd prefer if you can let me know the solution in Marmalade. But if not possible, kindly let me know the solution at least in Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution after searching in the marmalade example. Following is the steps for to get the total count -

1.First you need to authenticate the player to gamecenter, it's like Login. THe authentication method is -

```
s3eIOSGameCenterAuthenticate(AuthenticationCallback, NULL);
```

2.Next we need to load the scores from the leaderboard

```
s3eIOSGameCenterLeaderboardLoadScores(leaderboard,loadScoreCallBack);
```

3.Now in the callback method i.e. `loadScoreCallBack`, you will get the `TotalCount`.

```
void loadScoreCallBack(s3eIOSGameCenterLoadScoresResult* result)
{
    int TotalCount= result->m_ScoreCount;
}
```